# Stacking things of different thickness to approximate desired thickness

Tags: algorithms

I have $N$ objects of different thickness. Is there an algorithm to determine which of those objects should be stacked on each other to get as near to a desired thickness as possible? (I don't want to numerically check every combination.)

Comment: Is the thickness continuous or discrete? If the thickness is discrete (or can be discretized), do you have a relatively small upper bound on the desired thickness? If so, something similar to the dynamic programming algorithm for subset sum might work.

Comment: It's more like thought experiment but it comes from our lab. Sometimes we have to rise sample let's say by 6 cm and we use anything what we can find from mobile phone to paperbox, or phone on paper box. Idea was what that if we measure thickness of things on our desks and we put it in a database, we could have code in which we write desired thickness and it would return combination of things to use.

Comment: This sounds like a variant of the "bin packing" problem.  If you read up on that (e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) it may give you some clues.

Answer (score 2):

This is as hard as the subset sum problem.  The subset problem asks "is there a way to get exactly the desired thickness?".  Obviously, if we could solve your problem, we could also solve the subset sum problem.  Unfortunately, the subset sum problem is NP-hard, so your problem will be too.

In practice you can try using an approximation algorithm for the subset sum problem, e.g., by rounding to the nearest integer (or to the nearest multiple of $1/k$ for some $k$) and then applying the dynamic programming algorithm for subset sum.  See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem